What does the filename "gmon.out" stand for?
The GNU compiler toolset has a profiler "gprof" for performance analysis of C++ programs. With the -pg switch, the gcc compiler will make executables that write a data file, "gmon.out", on each run. This can then be fed into the gprof tool for analysis.
Usually I can decode the abbreviation or acronym to which these command-line tools refer. For example, "gprof" seems to stand for the "GNU profiler". However, I'm coming up empty for an explanation on what the token "gmon" means.
What's the etymology/origin of the abbreviation or acronym to which "gmon.out" refers?
(Previously asked on Stack Overflow, but the feedback is that the etymology question is inappropriate there.)

If you check the manual you can see the the profile writing functions are all variations on "monitor", so we can assume that the "mon" in "mon.out" is an abbreviation of monitor

The monitor() function is a low level interface to the profil() system
call. The lowpc and highpc parameters are the addresses of two
functions in   a program that delimit the text range to profile.  If
the lowpc parameter   is 0 (zero), the monitor() function stops
profiling and writes out the data   output file mon.out.  The buffer
allocated must be one-half the size of the   text range to be sampled.

Since gprof is an evolution of prof, it seems obvious that they just added a g to mon.out

Thanks. Can you add a link to the manual source in question?

here where i found it : https://www3.physnet.uni-hamburg.de/physnet/Tru64-Unix/HTML/MAN/MAN3/1278____.HTM
